# Firestore Transaction security rules: caching and limits

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Imagine you execute a Firestore transaction on the client in which you create three documents: a, b, and c.

In the security rules, you do the following for:

- a: check if b and c exists with getAfter
- b: check if a and c exists with getAfter
- c: check if a and b exists with getAfter

So my question is whether this will result in 6 reads counting towards the limit or whether Firestore caches all reads and will only perform three (or even zero?) reads.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a document is read during the evaluation of a rule, reading the same document second time during the evaluation of that same rule will use the previously read data.  It will not incur an additional read.

Comment: I read the question as the client generating *3* separate transactions, each creating a document - thus evaluating rules three times.  I have to assume that changes your answer?

Comment: @LeadDreamer the question specifically says "a transction" (singular) that involves 3 documents.  For a transaction, all of the relevant rules will be evaluated in the same batch, and either they all allow all the writes, or the entire transaction fails.  If this is not the situation, the OP should update the question to say what is different.